# android tablet not waking up

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, alarm

I've got a cheap android tablet running Android 4.0.4 and it doesn't seem to be "waking" up when I want it to. So, when it shuts off after period of inactivity or when I put it to sleep (not powering it off, though), it won't "wake up" at a specified time via the built-in alarm clock or another app (like tune-in which has an alarm feature built into it). When I manually "wake it up" by pressing the power switch, the alarm that should have gone off before goes off after a few seconds.

Do I just have something disabled that is preventing it from waking up? Or is this possibly a hardware issue?

Comment: Which tablet do you have?  You seem to have posted a link to another question instead of the name of your tablet, which is rather odd.

Comment: sorry about that...I should have been more clear. The link was to a previous post I made where I was trying to find out what my tablet is and who the manufacturer is. To the best of my knowledge, it's a TWD_MID...I don't know much more about it than that.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I just have something disabled that is preventing it from waking up?

There's no user-visible setting in Android for disabling alarms. That would kind of defeat their purpose!  The only way you can have disabled alarms is if you've rooted the device and gone around uninstalling system apps or poking at the internals. If you have, we'd need to know a lot more detail on what you've done to know if that's the cause, and the fix would probably be to flash a new ROM.

This does sound like the kind of system integration error you might find on an incredibly cheap tablet. Not quite a hardware issue, but a bug in the device's software. If it is, the only way to fix it would be to try to get an update from the manufacturer, but if you don't even know who they are, you might be out of luck.

Comment: I believe the device was shipped with root access (I didn't root it myself but I opened up a terminal and did su with no problem). The only settings I've changed are the typical ones that are available to regular users in Android (I think)...so I wondered if one of those would cause my problem.
And you're right...I have no idea who the manufacturer is and certainly not their website...so there's no update coming for me. Although, there is a setting that asks me if I want to check for system updates...which I've done a few times and (surprise surprise) there are no updates. Any other ideas?